# Which one is faster?

Tags: c, optimization, sse, simd, sse2

I am using SSE2 in gcc 4.4.3. In my program, I need to use say least (0 - 7) 8-bits of a 128-bit SIMD register. Please suggest a way in which I can retrieve the 8-bits quickly.

I tried with `_mm_movepi64_pi64` or `_mm_extract_epi16`, both of which gives similar performance in my program. I was trying with union approach also. `union{__m128i a1, int a2[4]}`. Though, in the test case, it gave good results, in my program, this approach was not very good.

Any ideas.. (which of the above mentioned three ways I should use?)

Comment: use whichever one works faster in your specific case.

Comment: i mean, is there any other way less expensive...?

Comment: then edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: What makes you think that you have a performance problem with this ? How do you imagine that you will get any more performance than using `_mm_extract_epi16`, which maps to a single instruction ?

Comment: thanx, i didn't know that. Then this is the best that can be achieved, I suppose..And any idea how the union approach compares with _mm_extract_epi16 to extract...

Comment: The union approach is just bad, and should not be used, because it forces the compiler to write the register back into memory to fetch the according memory to a GP register. NB: Please benchmark before asking. Sometimes even my answer may not hold true. (E.g. the register is always written to memory, so the compiler may reorder the read)

Comment: You're omitting half of the question: where do these 8 bits go? What do you need them for? You are not simply putting them in a `uint8_t` and forgetting them, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

`_mm_movepi64_pi64` moves from XMM to MMX registers.  There's no way it's the right choice, unless you want to do some more SIMD in MMX registers, and your code runs out of XMM regs.

If you want the bits as an array index or something, they have to be in a GP register, in which case you want SSE4.1 `_mm_extract_epi8`.

If you need to stick to SSE2, this should be the fastests way to get byte 5 of `xmm0`:

```
pextrw eax, xmm0, 2
movzx eax, ah
```

So this should hopefully get the compiler to be efficient like that:

```
(uint8_t)(_mm_extract_epi16(var, n/2) >> ((n%2) * 8))
```

Less efficient would be a shift-by-bytes `_mm_bsrli_si128` (`psrldq`) to put the byte you want into the low byte of an xmm reg, then `movd` (`_mm_extract_epi16(var, 0)` emits `movd`, not `pextrw r32, xmm, 0`, fortunately).  This way you don't have to do anything extra if the byte you want is an odd-numbered byte that pextw would leave in the high 8 of a result.  Still no easy way to use this with an index that isn't a compile-time constant.

Storing 16B to memory and loading the element you want should be fairly good.  (What you'll probably get with the union approach, unless the compiler optimizes it to a `pextract` instruction).  The compiler will use a 16B-aligned location on the stack.  Thus store->load forwarding should work fine in this case, so the latency will be low.  If you need two separate elements into two separate integer variables, this is probably the best choice, maybe beating multiple `pextrw`